# How can I create a view like this in sencha touch 2?

Tags: view, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I need to create a view like this in sencha touch. I'm a beginner . Please help me. I'm not getting tap event on component.

[image]

My Code

```
config: {
    defaults: {
        margin: 10
    }, layout: {
        type: 'hbox'
    },
    items: [{

        flex:1,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'component', flex: 10,
                html: 'Flex: 1', style: 'background-color: lightgray'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'spacer',flex:1
            },
            {
                xtype: 'component', flex: 10,
                html: 'Flex: 2', style: 'background-color: pink'
            }
        ]
    }, {

        flex: 1,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'component', flex: 10,
                html: 'Flex: 3', style: 'background-color: orange',
                handler:function() {
                    console.log('Tapped !');
                }


            },
            {
                xtype: 'spacer',flex:1
            },
            {
                xtype: 'component', flex: 10,
                html: 'Flex: 4', style: 'background-color: lightblue'
            }
        ]


    }]
```

Comment: Please post what code you have tried.

Comment: @Harikishnan I downvote your question because you didn't show what have you tried and just ask people to do work for you. But do not serial downvotes other user as a revenge since your account will probably being suspended for voting irregularities.

Comment: The reason why you the tap event is not working is that there is not handler config for Ext.Component. There is only a handler config for Ext.Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Ext.dataview.DataView. You will get examples from github.